# material-ui-next - Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the below component using material-ui 1.0.0-beta 31. The typography styles do not display on the page and all of the text has the same styling. Could someone explain what I've done wrong, please?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const LearningPage = (props, { authUser }) =>
  <div>
    <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
      benevent
    </Typography>
    <Typography >adjective</Typography>
    <Typography component="p">
      well meaning and kindly.<br />
      {'"a benevolent smile"'}
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="headline" gutterBottom>
      Headline
    </Typography>
  </div>

export default LearningPage;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `variant` prop does not exist in material-ui 1.0.0-beta 31. As specified in [the release notes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.32), the `variant` prop was introduced in beta 32.

Prior to beta 32, the `type` prop had the same role as the `variant` prop. Here's the [commit](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/d1027abcac132925e2a2fca8f63a47aedb83f101#diff-3e8b4858e53fac1e39c0bc5259c015f1) where the change was made, and here's [the issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/10101) where the change is discussed, if you're interested.

So, you have two options to fix this problem:

1. Upgrade to beta 32.
2. Stay at beta 31 and rename `variant` to `type`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on material-ui@1.0.0-beta.31. Updating the material-ui to 1.0.0-beta.32 fixed the problem. Just run:
`npm install --save material-ui@next`